# Reverse engeneering the control of an inductor

Tags: transistors, schematics, reverse-engineering

I tried to make the schematics of a toaster of mine. I don't have access to the toaster anymore but here is a part of the schematics I got.
It shows the control of the inductance that acts as a magnet when current passes through it. It then lock the lever of the toaster and after some time, the CD4541 puts its output from vdd to gnd.

[image]

Vdd is about 20 V above GND and something like 1 mA goes into the base: the transistor is biased. In stationary mode there in no potential difference on the inductance, leading to a short circuit between Vdd and GND.

Is there a way for my circuit to work in the intended way? I would have thought that the best way to drive the impedance would have been to control the currant that goes through it by putting a resistor at the collector of the transistor.

Few hypothesis I got to explain what went wrong in my course of thinking:

- The transistor actually has a built-in resistor at his collector. There were no marking on the transistor. Would this be cheaper for the manufacturer to have this kind of transistor?
- Something is missing in my schematics.
- Vdd is not really DC but has some variations due to the poor rectification of the current.
- The serial resistor value of the inductor cannot be neglected.

Comment: A solenoid has considerable DC resistance; it is designed not to be a short circuit.

Answer (score 1):

1. Transistors are unlikely to have resistor on collector. In this case it would just waste power. The transistors that do have internal resistors have a divider on the base and it is called a "digital transistor".
2. It is likely there is nothing missing in the schematics. It could be wrong though.
3. VDD is likely to be considered DC even if it would have some ripple or be unregulated DC. The chip would not work if it's not DC.
4. This. The inductor wire is long and has resistance. It sets the current drawn when voltage is applied to it.

However, there must be some errors in the reverse-engineering, as it makes no sense. There is a PNP transistor. Current can't enter the base. Under normal circumstances there would be current exiting the base, not entering. Pushing the button would toast the transistor immediately, by passing unlimited current through the EB junction. The resistor R10 would also make sure the transistor is always on and thus coil always enregized, regardless of the chip output.

It is possible that in place of the PNP transistor you drew, there is really a NPN transistor driving the coil in emitter follower mode, so it would drive it at approximately half of VDD supply voltage.

Comment: Yes indeed, I only had clues for the transistor the letter Q and ECB markings. How do you compute that the potential is halved ?

Comment: @InfiniteLooper There is an arbitrary VDD and two arbitrary resistors that are equal in value, so assuming the IC has near zero output impedance and assuming the transistor base draws almost no current, the voltage at base must be exactly half of VDD. And then there is approximately 0.7V of Vbe drop.

Comment: Is that a Vce about 10V ?

Answer (score 0):

> The transistor actually has a built-in resistor at his collector. There were no marking on the transistor. Would this be cheaper for the manufacturer to have this kind of transistor ?

The transistor does not have a built-in resistor.

> Something is missing in my schematics

The diagram is incorrect. Pressing SW? will place 20V from emitter to base, destroying the transistor. If the switch is not pressed: with OUTPUT low there will be a flow of about 18mA through the base. With OUTPUT high there will be about 9mA through the base.

The Manual Resest (MR) is grounded, so this circuit will never come out of reset.

> Vdd is not really DC but has some variations due to the poor rectification of the current

Measure the rectifier output with and without load to see how much the voltage changes.

> The serial resistor value of the inductor cannot be neglected

As mentioned in the comments, the inductance is part of a solenoid that will have the appropriate series resistance built-in based on the current and  voltage requirements.

The 1mA base current reported in the OP is too small based on a 20V supply.

I suggest that you retrace the wiring.

Comment: Indeed, I did the computation quickly and it more 10mA than 1mA